# how can i send data of H3 tag to my component in IONIC angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have the two  ngif in my html file, but i want to only send just the value of one h3 to my component on click

```
  <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let item of drivers"  (click)="presentAlertpayment()">


     <div *ngIf="item.distance.toFixed(1) > 2.0 && item.distance.toFixed(1) <= 4.1">

      <h3><b>Amount:</b> ₦{{priceforKM2}} </h3>
     </div>


     <div  *ngIf="item.distance.toFixed(1) > 2.0 && item.distance.toFixed(1) <= 4.1">

      <h3 ><b>Amount:</b> ₦{{priceforKM3}} </h3>
     </div>

 </ion-item>
```

i have tried to us ngModel with the tags but its not working..

Answer (score 0):

You can move the event click to the divs and pass the value via params:

```html
  <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let item of drivers" >


     <div *ngIf="item.distance.toFixed(1) > 2.0 && item.distance.toFixed(1) <= 4.1"  (click)="presentAlertpayment(priceforKM2)">

      <h3><b>Amount:</b> ₦{{priceforKM2}} </h3>
     </div>


     <div  *ngIf="item.distance.toFixed(1) > 2.0 && item.distance.toFixed(1) <= 4.1"  (click)="presentAlertpayment(priceforKM3)">

      <h3 ><b>Amount:</b> ₦{{priceforKM3}} </h3>
     </div>

 </ion-item>
```

Comment: can u give an example pls?

Comment: i want to pick just the if statement that shows and send to my component using on click

Comment: It will do it, when you click on one of them will trigger what is showing. I don't know if I'm understanding you, but if you'd like to explain to me, you can do it :D

Comment: pls do u have whatsapp or skype pls so i can show u screenshot? i really need this help..been stucked for 3days :(

Comment: What you can do is put your piece of code in stackbltiz: https://stackblitz.com/. And after it you can put the link here and we can help you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdmukg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'm still not seeing the code, this link was the preview. What you need to do is save your code and after it click on the button Share with the new link

Comment: well i am not able to...compiling for almost an hour now after i clicked save

Comment: i am passing other items like this, which works.   (click)="presentAlertpayment(item.id,item.phone,item.fullname,item.coverImage,item.lat,item.lng)">

Comment: You can pass the item fully: (click)="presentAlertpayment(item)